# Hadoop - detect last record of the input split

Tags: hadoop, built-in

I have a MapReduce job, whose map tasks use TextInputFormat. I would like to be able to know, in the map function, when the end of the split is reached (i.e. the last record has just been passed to the map function).

I know that there are some built-in counters (e.g.: Map Input Records counter which counts the Input Records consumed so far by **ALL** mappers but that's not what I need).

Could I use one of these build in counters ?

If not, do you know how I could get this information in my map tasks ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your logic in the `Mapper.cleanup(Context)` method (or `Mapper.close()` for the old mapred api), this is called after the last record has been processed by your map method.

Comment: Yes I knew about the cleanup(Context) but I'm using the old api.
I got it : Mapper.close() in the old one.
I'm tempted to starting using the new API but it's kind of under-documented.

Comment: One more observation/question: in the old API Mapper.close() doesn't allow me to write/collect as I can't access the OutputCollector from close. Would it be a good design pattern to have an instance var in the mapper class and assign it the value of the outputColletor passed as parameter to map ?
If not, I should definitely switch to the new API, as I have to write from the cleanup/close method.

Comment: This is your only option (to store a reference to the output collector). I would definitely switch to the new API - depends on your hadoop version i guess as some things haven't been ported from mapred to mapreduce (input and output formats mainly)

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it by changing record reader in the ipnut format. This custom record reader will maintain current line and the next one (like small pre-fetch). Thus it will know when there is no more lines and can indicate it to the mapper.

Comment: Yes , that would solve the problem but I think it's a much bigger effort than the solution in the other answer.

Comment: Yep, but it will be "after" the last record. And if you want to do something specific with the record - it might be too late. Beacuse of it i suggested this way